# HttpServletRequest stored in model gets replaced

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, el

I'm working on a legacy code (Spring 2.5.x, Java 1.5), where controller passes Http Servlet Request to view like this:

```
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Map attributes = new HashMap();
        attributes.put("httpRequest", request);
        return new ModelAndView("/path/to/page.jsp", attributes);

    }
```

However what happens is that httpRequest attribute does indeed exist in the JSP Page context, but it contains current request (JSP page) and not the original (controller). The passed request is being used to extract some information from the URL. It appears that I can get around that problem by using a bunch of "javax.servlet.forward.*" attributes. This however puzzles me as it is pretty simple thing and I'd be happy to get it to work anyways or at least know exactly why it doesn't work now. Anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, it is a **bad idea** to store the request as attribute of request. If you need specific data for the current request, you can retrieve it directly using `${requestContext}`, if you need to access to the URL, use `${requestContext.requestURL}`. If you need to access to parts of this URL to display it in client side, it would be better to parse the url in server side (controller) by first obtaining it using `StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();` and then setting the required data as attributes.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't elaborate a bit more on the "bad idea" as I'm extremally curious for the reason. Also, that "el" tag was a bit of missed assumption, since I work on tag library and I'm not using el directly. That being said, after trying many things I came up with a solution which is based on principals you have outlined, so I think you deserve an upvote and an accept.

Comment: @JacekPrucia storing the request inside the request attribute is like having a `Map<String, Object> map` and storing the map inside itself: `map.put("foo", map);`.